# removeIf() of List not working throwing - UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

When I try to remove the element from the list using `removeIf()`, It is throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
public class T {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(arr);
        stringList.removeIf((String string) -> string.equals("2"));
    }
}
```

Can some one help me understand why this is happening and how can I rectify this ?

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` returns an unmodifiable list. You can't change its content

Comment: As an aside, you don't need the type or parentheses in the lambda: these can be inferred.

Comment: @Ernest you can change the list, but only using `set` (or `replaceAll`). It is fixed-size, not unmodifiable.

Answer (score 10):

`Arrays.asList(arr)` returns a fixed sized `List`, so you can't add or remove elements from it (only replace existing elements).

Create an `ArrayList` instead:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are explicitly calling `Arrays.asList`, consider the alternative of not doing that, and create the filtered list directly:

```
Stream.of(arr)
    .filter(string -> !string.equals("2"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```